# Adding audio buffer [from file] to 'live' audio buffer [recording to file]

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

### What I'm trying to do:

Record up to a specified duration of audio/video, where the resulting output file will have a pre-defined background music from external audio-file added - **without further encoding/exporting after recording**.

As if you were recording video using the iPhones Camera-app, and all the recorded videos in 'Camera Roll' have background-songs. No exporting or loading after ending recording, and not in a separate AudioTrack.

---

### How I'm trying to achieve this:

By using `AVCaptureSession`, in the delegate-method where the (`CMSampleBufferRef`)sample buffers are passed through, I'm pushing them to an AVAssetWriter to write to file. As I don't want multiple audio tracks in my output file, I can't pass the background-music through a separate `AVAssetWriterInput`, which means I have to add the background-music to each sample buffer from the recording *while it's recording* to avoid having to merge/export after recording.

The background-music is a specific, pre-defined audio file (format/codec: m4a aac), and will need no time-editing, just adding *beneath* the entire recording, from start to end. The recording will never be longer than the background-music-file.

Before starting the writing to file, I've also made ready an `AVAssetReader`, reading the specified audio-file.

**Some pseudo-code**(threading excluded):

```
-(void)startRecording
{
    /*
        Initialize writer and reader here: [...]
    */
    
    backgroundAudioTrackOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput 
                            assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:
                                backgroundAudioTrack 
                            outputSettings:nil];

    if([backgroundAudioReader canAddOutput:backgroundAudioTrackOutput])
        [backgroundAudioReader addOutput:backgroundAudioTrackOutput];
    else
        NSLog(@"This doesn't happen");

    [backgroundAudioReader startReading];

    /* Some more code */

    recording = YES;
}
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
             didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
             fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    if(!recording)
        return;

    if(videoConnection)
        [self writeVideoSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    else if(audioConnection)
        [self writeAudioSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}
```

The `AVCaptureSession` is already streaming the camera-video and microphone-audio, and is just waiting for the `BOOL recording` to be set to `YES`. This isn't exactly how I'm doing this, but a short, somehow equivalent representation. When the delegate-method receives a `CMSampleBufferRef` of type Audio, I call my own method `writeAudioSamplebuffer:sampleBuffer`. If this was to be done normally, without a background-track as I'm trying to do, I'd simply put something like this: `[assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];` instead of calling my method. In my case though, I need to **overlap** two buffers before writing it:

```
-(void)writeAudioSamplebuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)recordedSampleBuffer
{
    CMSampleBufferRef backgroundSampleBuffer = 
                     [backgroundAudioTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

    /* DO MAGIC HERE  */
    CMSampleBufferRef resultSampleBuffer = 
                         [self overlapBuffer:recordedSampleBuffer 
                            withBackgroundBuffer:backgroundSampleBuffer];
    /* END MAGIC HERE */

    [assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:resultSampleBuffer];
}
```

---

### The problem:

I have to add incremental sample buffers from a local file to the live buffers coming in. The method I have created named `overlapBuffer:withBackgroundBuffer:` isn't doing much right now. **I know** how to extract `AudioBufferList`, `AudioBuffer` and `mData` etc. from a `CMSampleBufferRef`, but I'm not sure how to actually add them together - **however** - I haven't been able to test different ways to do that, because the real problem happens before that. Before the **Magic** should happen, I am in possession of two `CMSampleBufferRef`s, one received from microphone, one read from file, and this is the problem:

**The sample buffer received from the background-music-file is different than the one I receive from the recording-session.** It seems like the call to `[self.backgroundAudioTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];` receives a large number of samples. I realize that this might be *obvious* to some people, but I've never before been at this level of media-technology. I see now that it was wishful thinking to call `copyNextSampleBuffer` each time I receive a sampleBuffer from the session, but I don't know when/where to put it.

As far as I can tell, the recording-session gives **one** audio-sample in each sample-buffer, while the file-reader gives **multiple** samples in each sample-buffer. Can I somehow create a *counter* to count each received recorded sample/buffers, and then use the first file-sampleBuffer to extract each sample, until the current file-sampleBuffer has no more samples 'to give', and then call [..copyNext..], and do the same to that buffer?

As I'm in full control of both the recording and the file's codecs, formats etc, I am **hoping** that such a solution wouldn't ruin the 'alignment'/synchronization of the audio. Given that both samples have the same sampleRate, could this still be a problem?

---

### Note

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I see no immediate reason why it shouldn't.
Also worth mentioning that when I try to use a Video-file instead of an Audio-file, and try to continually pull video-sampleBuffers, they align up perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiarized with AVCaptureOutput, since all my sound/music sessions were built using AudioToolbox instead of AVFoundation. However, I guess you should be able to set the size of the recording capturing buffer. If not, and you are still get just one sample, I would recommend you to store each individual data obtained from the capture output in an auxiliar buffer. When the auxiliar buffer reaches the same size as the file-reading buffer, then call `[self overlapBuffer:auxiliarSampleBuffer withBackgroundBuffer:backgroundSampleBuffer];`

I hope this would help you. If not, I can provide example about how to do this using CoreAudio. Using CoreAudio I have been able to obtain 1024 LCPM samples buffer from both microphone capturing and file reading. So the overlapping is immediate.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good idea. I have been so focused on trying to find the opposite way of doing this (getting one sample out of many, instead of waiting for one to become many). This would however mean that writing won't happen continuously through recording but in batches, so if this won't affect quality or frame-rate, it could be a possible solution! I would very much like an example, even using CoreAudio.

Comment: Here: http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Download.html there is a magnificent project related to the creation of Audio Sessions using CoreAudio. I have been using it as a model for creating my customized sessions for iOS.

Comment: Then you have to focus on `readAudioFilesIntoMemory` method in `MixerHostAudio.m`. There `soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataLeft` stores the samples of the complete audiofile. I recommend you to copy them into a new buffer. Then if you look at `micLineInCallback` in `MixerHostAudio.m`you would find the callback that process the input samples. You would find the input samples in `sampleBufferLeft` by frames. Then if you only overlap this samples orderly (regarding the proper timestamp) over the file buffer, you would achieve your goal.